# Can I change my character's face without starting over?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

From what I've seen online, the appearance of your character's face depends on your answers to the questions you're asked while on the train. But I haven't found anything on how (or even *if*) I can change it without starting over. I didn't know this when I started, and now I'm stuck with a rather weird face. Is it possible to change it? How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your face itself cannot be changed after the beginning of the game. Only your hair and eye colour can be changed.

Comment: Note that you can make a Mii mask at Shampoodle's or wear a helmet which completely covers the face. But under those the face will always be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change your eye shape in the game. You can change your hairstyle and eye colour at [Shampoodle](http://www.thonky.com/animal-crossing-new-leaf/shampoodle/) once it's unlocked.

Answer (score -1):

You can't change your face in the game. You can change your and eye colour though.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. This information is already in the accepted answer. Do you have additional information?